# How to transform this third order nonlinear differential equation in to a first order system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

> Transform the differential equation
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> u'''(t) = \sin(u''(t)) - u^2(t), & t > 0, \\
> u^{(i)} = u_i \quad \text{for } i \in \{0, 1, 2\}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   into an equivalent system of first order ordinary differential equations.

I know how to carry out this procedure for linear systems but I am stuck because of the $\sin(u''(t))$ term.

For far I tried setting $x :\equiv u''$ und $y :\equiv u'$ and then substituting into the equation to obtain multiple differential equations in $x$ and $y$ but don't know how to simplify them to obtain the desired result:
$$
\begin{cases}
y'(t) = x(t), \\
x'(t) = \sin(x(t)) - u^2(t), \\
y''(t) = \sin(y'(t)) - u^2(t).
\end{cases}
$$
For context: This is the first part of a two part question where in the second part one is asked to find the iterative rule for Eulers method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Givn the equation

$u'''(t) = \sin (u''(t)) - (u(t))^2, \tag 1$

we set

$v(t) = u'(t), \tag 2$

and

$w(t) = v'(t) = u''(t); \tag 3$

so that

$w'(t) = v''(t) = u'''(t); \tag 4$

then the equation (1) may be written

$w'(t) = \sin (w(t)) - (u(t))^2, \tag 5$

which together with

$u'(t) = v(t), \tag 6$

$v'(t) = w(t), \tag 7$

becomes a first-order system in the three variables $u$, $v$, $w$.

We may in fact "unravel" (5)-(7) to recover (1), simply by substituting (3) and (4) back into (5).

Thus, equation (1) is equivalent to the system (5)-(7).